# Memory resource ( strdup )

Tags: c, memory-leaks, alsa, strdup

I call strdup to duplicate the 'card' string in set_device( devname )
set_device( devname ) 
and then I use 'card' to open mixer:

devname is in format hw:0/Mic

```
static char *card, *channel;
static snd_mixer_t *handle = NULL;
static snd_mixer_elem_t *elem = NULL;
static long min, max, vol;

static void open_mixer( void )
{
        int err;
        static snd_mixer_selem_id_t *sid = NULL;
        if ((err = snd_mixer_open (&handle, 0)) < 0) {
            return;
        }
        if ((err = snd_mixer_attach (handle, card)) < 0) {   /* memory leak */
            goto error;
        }
        if ((err = snd_mixer_selem_register (handle, NULL, NULL)) < 0) {
            goto error;
        }
        if ((err = snd_mixer_load (handle)) < 0) {
            goto error;
        }
        snd_mixer_selem_id_malloc(&sid);
        if (sid == NULL)
            goto error;
        snd_mixer_selem_id_set_name(sid, channel);
        if (!(elem = snd_mixer_find_selem(handle, sid))) {
            goto error;
        }
        if (!snd_mixer_selem_has_playback_volume(elem)) {
            goto error;
        }
        snd_mixer_selem_get_playback_volume_range(elem, &min, &max);
        if ((max - min) <= 0) {
            goto error;
        }
        snd_mixer_selem_id_free(sid);
        return;

error:
        if (sid)
            snd_mixer_selem_id_free(sid);
        if (handle) {
            snd_mixer_close(handle);
            handle = NULL;
        }
        return;
}

int set_device( const char *devname )
{
        int i;

        if (card) free(card);
        card = strdup( devname );
        if( !card ) return -1;

        i = strcspn( card, "/" );
        if( i == strlen( card ) ) {
            channel = "Mic";
        } else {
            card[i] = 0;
            channel = card + i + 1;
        }
        open_mixer();
        if (!handle) {
            fprintf( stderr, "mixer: Can't open mixer %s, volume unavailable.\n", card );
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Please help me to prevent memory leak after call strdup

Comment: The key to avoiding memory leaks is to free allocated memory once you're done with it...

Comment: static char *card=NULL, *channel=NULL;  You can't assign to "Mic" to channel because it doesn't have any memory associated with it, just a pointer.  You might be better off with char *channel[10] = {};

Answer (score 0):

The function *strdup* allocates memory with *malloc*. If you want to avoid memory leak because of *strdup* you **must** free the return value of strdup (in your case the variable *card*) when you are no longer using the data.

Here is the part of the *strdup* man that states this :

```
char *strdup(const char *s);
```

> The  *strdup()*  function  returns a pointer to a new string which is a duplicate of the string s.  Memory for the new string is obtained with *malloc(3)*, and can be
>          freed with *free(3)*.